# How to create same name file for different build?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have one configuration .js file, and I want to make second file with same name for other build configuration.

app.js - for debug and
app.js - for production

I tried manually change `Condition` in the .csproj, but I can't make same file names.

```
 <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Stage' ">
    <Content Include="app\scripts\app-config.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Stage' ">
    <Content Include="app\scripts\app-config.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Would this work? Rename the files app-config.debug.js and app-config.prod.js and use MSBuild Move or something similar to rename them to app-config.js while building the project.

Comment: Yes. It is work, but not clear solution. I try to find something better